# Override CSS background image in Wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to remove the default background image icon of the AddToAny Wordpress plugin. As you can see in the URL below, the blue icon would like to be replaced by the black gear. Problem is the blue icon is brought in by inline styles, with an !important declaration within the plugin. :(

Their inline code:

```
.a2a_dd.addtoany_share_save {
    background: url(http://www.dlillianphotography.com/staging/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/favicon.png) no-repeat scroll 4px 0px !important;
}
```

My code, hoping nesting/hierarchy would help:

```
.social .row:first-of-type .addtoany_list .a2a_dd.addtoany_share_save {
    background: #fff !important;
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using jQuery

```
('.a2a_dd.addtoany_share_save').removeAttr( "style" );
```

then your style will works

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using .setProperty()

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.a2a_dd.addtoany_share_save').each(function () {
        this.style.setProperty( 'background', '#fff', 'important' );
     });
  });
```